# Proving convergence of $|A| = \sqrt{A^*A}$ in the norm and strong operator topologies

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of bounded linear operators on some Hilbert space, and let $|A| = \sqrt{A^*A}$. I would like to prove the following two statements:

1. If $A_n \rightarrow A$ is norm then $|A_n| \rightarrow |A|$ in norm.
2. If $A_n \rightarrow A$ strongly and $A_n^* \rightarrow A^*$ strongly, then $|A_n| \rightarrow |A|$ strongly.

If possible, I would like to do so without resorting to the spectral theorem. For both problems I am having some trouble showing that the square root of the operator preserves convergence. Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3471294/convergence-absolute-value-operators

Comment: WLOG you may assume that $\|A_n\|\le 1.$ Then you can  use the direct formula $0\le B\le I$ $$\sqrt{B}=I-\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n(I-B)^n$$ where $$
c_n=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(2n-1)}.
$$

Comment: @Gerd Thank you, I will take a look at that question.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you for your comment. What allows one to write any bounded linear operator as an infinite sum?

Comment: The sum representing $\sqrt{B}$ is absolutely covergent. The formula is based on the MacLaurin expansion $\sqrt{1-x}=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nx^n,$ for $0\le x\le 1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks. And why may we assume that $\|A_n\| \leq 1$?

Comment: The sequence $\|A_n\|$ is bounded, i.e $\|A_n\|\le m$ for some positive constant. Consider rescaled sequence $B_n=m^{-1}A_n,$ and $B=m^{-1}A.$ The assumptions and conclusions for $B_n$  and $A_n$ are equivalent.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you for all your helpful comments.